# Обновление сервера Intellij idea

Tags: java, apache, eclipse, intellij-idea, update

В intellij ideа, когда запущен сервер, я нажимаю обновить и табличка "Restart server" "Redeploy server", оба пересобирают артифакты. Можно ли как-то обновить проект, то есть применить изменения в jsp например как в eclipse?

Comment: кнопка debug - update resources, если я правильно понял вопрос

Comment: Понял то правильно, но у меня нету такого, есть только еще Hot swap classes - это тоже самое?